# toc float and hidden object rmarkdown html

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a problem with my rmarkdown and hidden objects. Here I have a button to display a secondary category. All great for the button but I have issue with my toc float, if the categorie is hidden, my toc float is blocked and I can't scroll in it anymore.

```
---
title: "TEST"
output: 
  html_document:
    number_sections: true
    table-of-contents: true
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: true
      smooth_scroll: true
    toc_depth: 2
    section-divs : true
---

# Some categorie{-}

**Description :** \ \
blablabla

\ Click to show other variables \
<button name="button" onclick="toggleVisibility('other_var')" >All variables</button> 

## Principal variables {- .tabset}
### var1
### var2


## Secondary variables{- .tabset #other_var style="display: none;" .toggle}
### va3
### var4
```

I've seen I can use the {.unlisted} but actually i would like to keep my section "Secondary variables" visible in the toc if possible.